# FuzzyFinder Bug

Tags: vim

I just installed [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) (including the L9 library), but I can't seem to start it! It should be <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> right? I am on [Mac OS X v10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion).

Also, ":help :fuf" returns nothing. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Go through the same link you posted. It has all the info I guess.

Comment: ok great, but what <C-w> represents? if I want to map "cmd+b" to open the buffer command, |:FufBuffer|, what do I write in my .vimrc file?

Comment: <C- stands for control, not command. See `:help <D-`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the default keybindings of a vim plugin

Answer (score 4):

FuzzyFinder provides various `:Fuf...` commands, but no default mappings.

You can define such mappings in your `.vimrc` file, like this:

```
:nnoremap <D-t> :FufMruFile<CR>
```

The help tags need to be generated once; type

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```